# Securing a ubuntu server for dev purpose

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, firewall

I'm working on a website project with a friend, and we're using instances like Keycloak and MongoDB for our project. To avoid the need to install everything on each of our devices, I've rented a ubuntu server to run all these instances. The issue is that the server is currently accessible to anyone, which I want to prevent. This server is solely for development purposes, and I want only my friend and me to have access to it. Therefore, I'm looking for a straightforward solution to block all connections that aren't from my friend or me. I've already considered configuring the server to only allow specific IP addresses to access it, but I'm uncertain if that's the right approach. Perhaps there's an alternative solution, such as a configuration that always requires a password whenever someone tries to connect to the server. Thank you!

Comment: Does it not require a login & password now? Or a key (like ssh) you have? It really shouldn't just automatically give root access to whoever can connect...

Comment: Securing and limiting access to a server has been done many times before and is likely well documented. What research have you done prior to asking here? We solve single specific problems here, and this broad ask isn't really a good fit